# Print (or print preview) of multiple specified hidden sheets

Tags: excel, vba

new to this site, I hope someone can assist me with a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a workbook with 1 sheet/tab that will always be visible (input sheet) that is for user inputs. This is where I will have form control buttons to assign macros to. All other sheets will be hidden. The hidden sheets are forms that are individualized via the unhidden sheet (input sheet). I would like to have a button that will allow a user to click (run a macro), that will either print or print preview the hidden sheets that are specified in the macro. The hidden sheets name as an example are "Front" & "Back", But there is potential for there to be more sheets in the future that I would have to of course change the macro to accommodate.
Update most of the Coding hits a road block once i protect the workbook. So a workaround is the sheets i want hidden, i can set their visibility to "Very Hidden". This solves the protecting the workbook at all, and limits what can be seen regardless. So it eliminates the password portion of the code.

What I do have now that works (except for when I hide the sheets or protect the workbook).

```
Sub PrintRoundingSheets()

On Error Resume Next

Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Array("Front", "Back")).PrintPreview
'Can substitute PrintOut as well and it works in this instance

End Sub
```

What I do have now that works (except for when I hide the sheets or protect the workbook).

```
Sub PrintRoundingSheets()

On Error Resume Next

Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Array("Front", "Back")).PrintPreview
'Can substitute PrintOut as well and it works in this instance

End Sub
```

When i try this with hidden pages nothing happens, i know there lines to hide & unhide such as:

```
Sub PrintRoundingSheet()
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Sht In Sheets(Array("Front", "Back"))
Sht.Visible = True
Sht.PrintOut
Sht.Visible = False
Next Sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

OR.............

```
Sub PrintRoundingSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Array("Front", "Back"))
.Visible = False
.PrintPreview
.Visible = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue with unhiding and re-hiding?

Also, is there a reason why you want to go to print preview and not just print? (or save to PDF) You may be able to do that on hidden worksheets

Comment: the hiding and re-hiding I'm trying to eliminate as this will be a tool utilized by some staff that is unnecessary information. trying to keep things as simple as possible. I want the print preview because that gives the user the option to either print directly (and select the duplex option they want - double sided), or print to pdf and save as.    I had already tried the print option as well, it has the same error/issue when they are hidden.

Comment: AFAIK you must unhide what you want to print. The bottom snippet has .visible = false twice, typo?

Comment: Yes that 2x false after .visible was a type. the first was supposed to be .visible = true. At least that's what I tried and it did not work.

Comment: Alright, i got it to work (halfway) however i can only get it to work for one sheet, any suggestions on how to get it to work for 2 specific sheets at the same time. What worked is as follows:                                                                                                                                        
    Sub PrintRoundingSheet()
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    With Sheet2
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .PrintPreview
    errhandler:
    .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End With

    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do it. What you need to do to update for your purposes is:

- Update the line that starts "SavePath = Environ..." to create and store the PDF filepath that you want to use (you can e.g. put in the workbook name or whatever)
- Update the section that starts "Create array of names..." to be an array that stores the worksheet names that you need. If each button has a set range of worksheets, you can pass that in

From "Save file" and down should be good to go

```
Sub PDFworksheets()
''''''''''''''''''''
'Purpose:           [Purpose]
'Last updated:      [Name; Date]
''''''''''''''''''''

Dim SavePath                    As String
Dim WsToSave()                  As String
Dim i                           As Integer

''Prepare
'Store your save path
SavePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "SpreadsheetOutput.pdf"

'Create array of names of worksheets to print
ReDim WsToSave(1 To 2)
WsToSave(1) = "Sheet1"
WsToSave(2) = "Sheet2"


''Save file
'Show hidden worksheets
For i = 1 To UBound(WsToSave)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WsToSave(i)).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next i

'Print
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WsToSave).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, SavePath

'Re-hide worksheets
For i = 1 To UBound(WsToSave)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WsToSave(i)).Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next i


''Notify user
MsgBox "Worksheets printed succesfully"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @JakeyG, It works, but only for 1 page.  Whatever is in the WStoSave(1) under the "create array of names" is the only sheet that gets outputted. I switched the two sheet names to verify. I also verified that both sheets in VBA has the visibility set to xlsheetHidden.

Answer (score 0):

Heres what i found works for me. Thank you all for the assistance.

```
Sub PrintRoundingSheet()
Sheets("Front").Visible = True
Sheets("Back").Visible = True
On Error Resume Next
Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Array("Front", "Back")).PrintPreview
Sheets("Front").Visible = xlVeryHidden
Sheets("Back").Visible = xlVeryHidden

End Sub
```